# Why did the hover-chairs deploy oxygen masks when the captain activated the Holo-Detector and the passengers went to the Lido Deck?

Tags: wall-e

Why did the hover-chairs deploy oxygen masks when the captain activated the Holo-Detector and the passengers went to the Lido Deck?

[image: Screenshot of oxygen masks]

Comment: A good question. The script seems to indicate that it's an automated safety procedure but it doesn't say *why* it was there

Comment: My personal guess is it's because real life astronauts wear their helmets during take off and landing.

Comment: @Kai They weren't needed because the people slipped out of their hover chairs and still survived the landing.

Comment: @sag Real life astronauts don't technically need them either from what I understand. It's an additional level of safety in case life support fails, as takeoff and landing are the most precarious parts of the trip.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.seeker.com/amphtml/near-mutiny-on-apollo-7-colds-tempers-marred-mission-1767965064.html Apollo 7 is an example, where the procedure said for the astronauts to wear their helmets during re-entry, but the astronauts refused, and they landed helmet-less.

Comment: This post was locked for content dispute once. I don't think it's a good idea to start that all over again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the ship performs a hyperjump, the passengers are thrown clear off their feet and experience a considerable amount of stress including multiple head impacts.

[image: Animated gif showing the Axiom accelerating into a warp effect, then moving through star lines. The clip then cuts to a field full of the Axiom's passengers, in matching red jumpsuits, who had just stood up en mass from their float chair all being thrown to the ground]

The [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Wall-E.html) describes the hoods as the space equivalent of "*life preservers*", basically a wise precaution against any sort of incident that might occur during hyperflight when seated in a mobile chair. Note that there's no good indication that these masks contain an oxygen breathing apparatus. If anything they seem to be more geared toward ***protection from head injuries*** given that they're labelled

> "Emergency Safety Helmet"

on the side of the hood and don't fit flush to the face or neck.

---

Per the script

> VARIOUS ANGLES AROUND THE AXIOM

> ...Floodlights kick on everywhere...
> ...The LIDO DECK POOLS automatically cover up...
> ...Stray PASSENGERS pause to take in the alarms...
> ...**SPACE-LIFE PRESERVERS burst from their hover chairs**...
> ...**Inflate around their necks**...
> ...GREEN LINES appear on the floors...
> ...SLEEPING PASSENGERS are involuntarily led out of their cabins...
> ...Every hover chair follows the illuminated lines...